# Maximization of quadratic form subject to a set constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, constraints, hessian-matrix

Given a quadratic form $x^tAx$ where the matrix $A$ is symmetric and $x^tx$ = 1, we can deduce that the maximum of the quadratic form is the first eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ (also, the first eigenvector is the direction for maximizing the quadratic form).

What if I have a set constraint such that $x \subseteq D$, where $D$ consists of a finite set of vectors. I want to choose the element(or the candidate) from $D$ which maximizes the quadratic form given symmetric matrix $A$ (norm of the elements in $D$ is 1 and $A$ is a hessian matrix).

How can I seek for the best element that maximizes the quadratic form?

Thank you.

Comment: You could consider the QP problem where, instead of $x\in D$, you relax to $x\in\operatorname{conv}(D)$. Under certain conditions the solution of this QP will be one of the corners of the convex hull, i.e. one of the elements of $D$.

Comment: Dear @Hyperplane, thank you for your novel comment. Is the "conv(D)" a convex set of elements in D? I'm quite not familiar with this topic, so may I ask for a more detailed explanation or some materials I can refer to? Thank you!

Comment: Actually upon reading your question a second time, why don't you just brute force it? How large is $D$? (and $\operatorname{conv}(D)$ refers to the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) spanned by those vectors)

Comment: D is not that large. However, in my case, getting a Hessian matrix(A) is non-trivial. Therefore, I want to utilize the first eigenvector of A(Hessian matrix), which maximizes the quadratic form if the constraint is not given. In my situation, I can acquire the first eigenvector of A using the power method without getting the real values of the matrix A(Hessian matrix). So I want something like (if valid) to find the element in D that maximizes the inner product with the first eigenvector of A. I want to know whether this method is valid or perhaps other workarounds? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry the question wasn't clear.

Comment: As you commented, brute-forcing can(and maybe shohuld) be used, but not with the raw quadratic form.

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question to include this crucial information. You say that $A$ is a Hessian in your case. Do you by any chase work with auto-differentiation software like tensorflow/pytorch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly brute force this problem: Given a function $f\colon\mathbb R^N \to\mathbb R, \theta\mapsto f(\theta)$ with Hessian $H=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \theta}$, then the quadratic form $x^T H x$ can be computed without explicitly computing $H$:

$$ x^T H x =  x^T \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial^2 \theta} x = x^T\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} x\Big) $$

Once you implement $f$ in a language that supports [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) such as [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/) or [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), you can compute it efficiently via

```
  z = grad(f, theta).dot(x)
xHx = grad(z, theta).dot(x)
```

At no point in this process is the matrix $H$ explicitly constructed. If you have enough RAM you can also concatenate all $x$ vectors and run everything in a single swoop (using appropriate tensorcontraction instead of inner product `.dot`).

Comment: Thank you for such a novel answer @Hyperplane. Though I have a question, what if the $f$(function) depends on $x$? For example, for a given input $d$, $f$(function) is a KL divergence of $p(\cdot|d)$ and $p(\cdot|d+x)$. In this case, do I have to get gradients of every case for the elements in $x$? or perhaps another workaround? Again, thank you so much for your kind work.

Comment: @JJumSSu In that case all you need to do is tell the program to not take gradients for that input (e.g. `torch.no_grad` or `tf.stop_gradient`)

Comment: thank you. so do I have to backpropagate for every case(every element in D)?

Comment: BTW, if possible, can you provide me with materials(maybe URL) regarding the quadratic programming with the convex hull constraint you mentioned? I'm just curious! I couldn't find suitable materials for myself. Thank you so much